# Missing environment variables when app is deployed to app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am new to node development struggling with getting the environment variables form the app engine . I am trying to deploy a web server to Google App engine.

During development I am using the "dotenv" package to get the variables.Everything is working as expected.

When deployed to engine using app.yaml. I am missing all the variables getting undefined.
Currently I am using node 12.5.0 and using `runtime: nodejs12` in the app.yaml.

```
runtime: nodejs12
env_variables:
  AccountID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  Token: "somethingrandom"
```

.env

```
AccountID=myacccountID
Token=mytoken
```

index.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

let accountid = process.env.AccountID
console.log(accountid);
```

on my local environment I am getting value correctly. 
But on the GAE i'm getting undefined

Previously I have even tried to include the .env file and  use the "dotenv" library in App engine and it worked. But it is not working now.

Comment: Edit your question and include a minimal example that shows this problem.

Comment: I have updated the sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to bother you guys. 
After 4 cups of coffee I finally figured the issue. 
In my env file I have AccountID as varraible but in my code I am using process.env.**accountID**

which is undefined.
Finally figured that. But I was wondering why the compiler didn't throw any error in the local machine.

Comment: This means that you provided incorrect details in the code sample in your question. Please edit your question to show the actual problem.

Comment: As I mentioned in the code . I .env variable set as 
`AccountID=xxxxxxx`

but in code I am calling below
`let accountID = process.env.accountID` 
you can see that when delcared in env filed I have variable start with upper case and in the code I am called with lowercase variable name